# How to make `D` apply chain rule on user-defined symbols as it does on `Dot` and `NonCommutativeMultiply`

Tags: function-construction, algebra, built-in-symbols

I have my own version of `Dot` called `mydot`, and it behaves quite similar to the built-in version in that it represents the non-commutative product of a string of objects.  Also, `mydot` is supposed to support differentiation that behaves in the same way as `Dot`.  But I am unable to get `D` to operate on `mydot` the same way `D` works on built-in `Dot`:

```
D[Dot[x, (x + a y), z], y]
```

> [image]

But

```
D[mydot[x, (x + a y), z], y]
```

> [image]

I tried:

```
Derivative[ndiff__][mydot][x__] := 
  ReplaceAll[Derivative[ndiff][Dot][x], Dot :> mydot];
D[mydot[x, (x + a y), z], y]
```

> [image]

As you can see, the serious problem I'm having is that it is pulling the factor `a` *outside* of `mydot`, which is incorrect.

Trying to get this to behave properly by making definitions of `Derivative` fails, because the chain rule has already been applied:

```
Derivative[ndiff__][mydot][x__] := stuff;
D[mydot[x, (x + a y), z], y]
```

How do I program `D` and `Derivative` to apply chain rule to the symbol `mydot` correctly?

> [image]

Comment: I strongly prefer against injecting code into a built-in function like this:  `ClearAttributes[D, Protected];
D[expr_, args__] :=
 Block[{$inD = True, result},
   result = (D[expr /. mydot[seq___] :> NonCommutativeMultiply[seq], 
       args]) /. NonCommutativeMultiply[seq___] :> mydot[seq];
   result
   ] /; ! TrueQ[$inD]
SetAttributes[D, Protected];`

Comment: What about defining the `UpValues` of **built-in** symbol `D[]`.

Comment: @ShutaoTANG How do you define `UpValues` when `mydot` can be arbitrarily deep inside of an expression?

Comment: Why not define a `myD` function? Something like `myD[expr_, 
  args__] := (D[expr /. mydot -> NonCommutativeMultiply, args]) /. 
  NonCommutativeMultiply -> mydot`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, Mathematica always differentiates function heads that contain the independent differentiation variables, unless the function head is listed in the "DifferentiationOptions"->"ExcludedFunctions" system options. So, we can get the behavior you want by adding `mydot` to this list:

```
SetSystemOptions[
    "DifferentiationOptions" -> 
    "ExcludedFunctions"-> DeleteDuplicates[
        Append[
            OptionValue[SystemOptions[], "DifferentiationOptions"->"ExcludedFunctions"],
            mydot
        ]
    ]
];
```

and then adding a custom differentiation rule for `mydot`:

```
mydot /: D[mydot[a__], y_] := D[Dot[a], y] /. Dot->mydot
```

Then, we have:

```
D[mydot[x, (x+a y), z], y]
```

mydot[x, a, z]

as desired. Here are the rest of @Jens' tests:

```
D[y^2 + 2 mydot[x + b y, (x + a y), z], y]
D[y^2 + 2 mydot[x, f[x + a y], z], y]
D[mydot[x, (x + a y^2), z], y, y]
```

> 2 y + 2 (mydot[b, x + a y, z] + mydot[x + b y, a, z])
>
> 2 y + 2 mydot[x, a f'[x + a y], z]
>
> mydot[x, 2 a, z]

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you can use the following:

```
ClearAll[dmydot, mydot]

Derivative[ndiff__][mydot][x__] := dmydot[ndiff][x];

dmydot /: Times[f__, dmydot[n1___, 1, n2___][x__]] := 
 mydot @@ MapAt[Times[f] &, {x}, Length[{n1}] + 1]
```

All I'm doing here is pull the inner derivative that came from the chain rule back into the `mydot` to replace the original entry at that position. This is done by defining the derivative as `dmydot` and giving it a rule that acts when something multiplies it. Now it can of course happen that this "something" also contains factors that were there even before the chain rule kicked in. But at least the operation of pulling such additional factors *into* the `mydot` product can never be incorrect. Whether you are willing to live with this possibility, I'm not sure...

Here are some tests:

```
D[y^2 + 2 mydot[x + b y, (x + a y), z], y]

(* ==> 2 y + 2 (mydot[b, x + a y, z] + mydot[x + b y, a, z]) *)
```

This now behaves exactly like `Dot`:

```
D[y^2 + 2 Dot[x + b y, (x + a y), z], y]

(* ==> 2 y + 2 (b.(x + a y).z + (x + b y).a.z) *)
```

Here is a more general function `f` inside `mydot`:

```
D[y^2 + 2 mydot[x, f[x + a y], z], y]

(* ==> 2 y + mydot[x, 2 a Derivative[1][f][x + a y], z] *)
```

I think this is all mathematically correct, and the main issue of unwanted inner derivatives in front of the product has been fixed. In addition, it also works with higher derivatives:

```
D[mydot[x, (x + a y^2), z], y, y]

(* ==> mydot[x, 2 a, z] *)
```

Comment: I'm assuming that the differentiation variables (`y`) is a scalar. Differentiation with respect to matrices or operators would require additional rules.

Comment: Yes, differentials are w.r.t scalar.  Also, so that it works with `Series` we need to define `Derivative` for higher order derivatives.  My proposal is to replace your first line with the following two:  `Derivative[ndiff__][mydot][x__] /; And @@ Thread[Less[{ndiff},2]] := dmydot[ndiff][x];` and `Derivative[ndiff__][mydot][x__]  /; Or @@ Thread[GreaterEqual[{ndiff},2]] := 0;`.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, that seems to work with `Series`, too. I guess `Series` doesn't do the same internal simplifications that happen when a higher-order `D` is encountered. By the way, I also had an idea based on using `Dt` instead of `D`... but I guessed you prefer sticking with `D`.

Comment: Any ideas with `Dt` are welcome too!  Thanks

Comment: But with `Dt`, you'd have to give up using `Series` - so I think it's of more limited usefulness. The good thing about `Dt` is that it allows you to identify what the differentiation variables is "after the fact," because there will always be `Dt[_,y]` terms that give it away. Then you can reverse the chain rule without affecting other prefactors.